# Mostrar plurales en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Hay alguna forma de pluralizar cadenas en Android? es decir para representar.

```
hay 1 objeto
hay 3 objetos
```

Actualmente lo que hago es tener dos recursos definidos en el `string.xml` y si el valor es más de `1` cargo uno o el otro.

Comment: Te refieres a que el valor que cambia sea una string?

Comment: Si es 1 se muestre objeto y si es más de 1 objetos, ahora mismo lo hago con dos entradas a String.xml y mediante un if en java cargo uno o el otro, me pregunto si hay algo más directo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que si no quieres utilizar 2 resources puede ir todo en 1, me explico

```
 <string name="huevos">hay %1$d %2$d</string>
```

Donde `%2$d` puede ser Huevo o Huevos

O de esta manera

```
<plurals name="numeroHuevos">
<item quantity="one">hay %d huevo</item>
<item quantity="other">hay %d huevos</item>
</plurals>
```

**EDIT**

```
int count = getCountHuevoa();
Resources res = getResources();
String cantidadHuevos =  res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.numeroHuevos, count, count);
```

Comment: lo de <plurals tiene muy buena pinta, como se carga en java con getString?

Comment: Edite @Webserveis  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals documentacion oficial!